# In Unity3D game engine, how to make a delay?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is only related to Unity3D, the game engine.

So let's say I have one line of code, and then another. How would I make a delay between those two lines of code. To repeat, I'm also doing this for Unity3D.

I've looked everywhere, but nothing will work.

Comment: I think you should take another approach. Invest some time in studying the [game loop](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/761922/Unity-and-Csharp-Game-Loop-Awake-Start-Update). Then, you can split your code to do something (your first line) and then execute something else (your second line) after some `Time.deltaTime` has passed. `Thread.Sleep` is almost always a very big no-no

Comment: never, ever, ever use "thread.sleep" (or "thread anything") in Unity.  of course, obviously, Unity has trivial timers built in.  it's just **Invoke**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a ***FRAME-BASED*** game engine, Unity of course, obviously, has every imaginable sort of timer and run loop control built-in.

It's absolutely trivial to make timers ...

```
   Debug.Log("Race begins!");
   // 3 seconds later, make the crowd cheer
   Invoke("CrowdCheers", 3f);
   // 7 seconds later, show fireworks
   Invoke("Fireworks", 3f);

   private void CrowdCheers()
    {
    crowd.Play();
    }

   private void Fireworks()
    {
    fireworks.SetActive(true);
    }
```

If you are more advanced with coding, you can use "coroutines". Coroutines are a ridiculously simple way to access the run loop.  Examples:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class demo : MonoBehaviour {
    // Details at: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Some start up code here...
        Debug.Log("Co-1");
        StartCoroutine("OtherThing");
        Debug.Log("Co-2");
    }

    IEnumerator OtherThing()
    {
        Debug.Log("Co-3");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
        Debug.Log("Co-4");
        DoOneThing();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        Debug.Log("Co-5");
        DoOtherThing();
    }

    void DoOneThing()
    {
        Debug.Log("Co-6");
    }

    void DoOtherThing()
    {
        Debug.Log("Co-7");
    }
}
```